# Smarty compile templates php

Tags: php, hash, smarty

My templates system use Smarty library.
Every form has hidden input with hash (token) for secure from CSRF.
Because of that, Smarty compile the page every refresh.

How to tell Smarty to not compile inputs or forms or any code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty compiles all templates. This is how it works. You cannot tell Smarty not to compile templates.  Smarty compiles templates but if you use variables in template, it will use variable, so if your CSRF token is variable it won't be stored in compiled template.

However probably you are talking here about caching. You should look at your caching settings to solve this or post some code to help understand your problem.

Comment: I use templates inside templates by {include}. In the included template I use vars. If I display it, It show the code after compile only the first template without the included template. Than what I do is $smarty->fetch twice. But than the first template's vars are strings and not variables anymore. How to solve that? Thank you.

Comment: @Upimform I don't know what you try to achieve, but this is how fetch function works. It works the same as display but it doesn't display it just returning the parsed template so you can save it into string. Nothing more.